# How to record the current tenant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

I am building a SaaS app based on Ruby on Rails.

Tenants have sub-domains.

The visit belongs to User, which is taken from the `#current_user`. Additionally I would also like to associate the visit with the current tenant. In my case it would be:

```
class Visit
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :ahoy_events, class_name: 'Ahoy::Event'

  belongs_to :site # the relationship with tenant
end
```

How can I hack things to record the current tenant?

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#track-additional-values

Answer (score 0):

So `:site` is in fact your tenant model?

Create some `ApplicationController` methods that let you store and retrieve your current tenant, which you can track in your session.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def current_tenant=(tenant)
    session[:tenant_id] = tenant.id
  end

  def current_tenant
    Site.find(session[:tenant_id])
  end

end
```